# saving recent searches to cookie

Tags: jquery

I initially was saving the user's recent searches to a sessions array (php) which works but i am having a hard time getting around the (shared) server settings - to make it last 30 days.  Since it's not sensitive data i thought I would retry this with jstorage/jquery instead. Is that possible across multiple pages? 
This is what i have right now but it's not working :( :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

if (jQuery.jStorage.get('test') != '') {
    jQuery.jStorage.set('test2', '<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>' );
} else {
    jQuery.jStorage.set('test', '<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>' );
}

jQuery.jStorage.setTTL('test', 30000);
jQuery.jStorage.setTTL('test2', 30000);
var index = jQuery.jStorage.index();
for(i in index) {
    var result = jQuery.jStorage.get(index[i]) + " ";
    jQuery('#mysearches').append('<li>' + result + '</li>');
}
});
```

is this even possible to do what I explained?  is there a better way? Any direction would be helpful.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using PHP, have you thought of `serialize()`ing your array and storing in a cookie with `setcookie()` rather than using jStorage?